# How can I recover my lost saves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I accidentally threw my Skyrim save into a folder I can't find.

Is there an easy way to recover it through Steam or something else? Nothing is in the recycle bin, so it's not deleted.

Comment: Next time you accidentally move a folder or file, and immediately realize it, try going to the Edit menu > Undo, or hit Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 7):

If you are positive you just misplaced them and didn't delete them (empty Recycle Bin is not a guarantee that the files are not deleted), try search for any files on your hard drive(s) that has the file ending `.ess`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular tool for finding misplaced Skyrim save directories that I'm aware of. You can use Windows Explorer's search function to look for a folder called "Skyrim" on your HDDs. You can also start Skyrim and have it redownload the saves from the cloud, though you may lose some of your saves that way, and you will have a junk folder clogging up your drive.

The default location for your Skyrim saves is your documents folder\My games\Skyrim